# Implement methods of an implemented List to an ArrayList

Tags: java

I know what to do with my programming code, but I just don't know why we have to do it.

My ArrayList class implements a List<E> interface. This means I have to copy all methods in my List interface to my ArrayList class. This is to stop the error of my ArrayList class saying: "ArrayList is not abstract and does not override abstract method iterator(int)" error. Can someone explain that to me in more detail?

Also: When I used the auto correct in NetBeans it says statements after each method "throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");". Why?

Here's my code:

```
public class ArrayList<E> implements List<E> {

    private E[] elementData;
    private int elementCount;
    private int capacityIncrement;
    private static final int INVALID_INDEX=-1;
    private static final int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 100;

    public ArrayList() {

        capacityIncrement = 0;
        elementData = (E[]) new Object[DEFAULT_CAPACITY];
    }

    public ArrayList(int capacity) {

        this.capacityIncrement = 0;
        this.elementData = (E[]) new Object[capacity];
    }

    public ArrayList(int capacity, int increment) {

        this.capacityIncrement = increment;
        this.elementData = (E[]) new Object[capacity];
    }

    private static class ArrayListIterator<E> implements Iterator<E> {
        private ArrayListIterator(ArrayList c) {

            elementData = c;
        }

    public interface List<E> {

    public int size();

    public boolean isEmpty();

    public void clear();

    public boolean contains(E element);

    public void add(E element);

    public boolean remove(E element);

    public E elementAt(int index);

    public int indexOf(E element);

    public void insertElementAt(E element, int index);

    public void removeElementAt(int index);

    public void setElementAt(E element, int index);


    public void removeDuplicates();

    public void trimToSize();

    public Iterator<E> iterator();

    public Iterator<E> iterator(int index);

    public String toString();
}
```

Comment: Perhaps take a look at the tutorial on [Interfaces](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html).

Comment: Are you sure you want to set `capacityIncrement = 0`?  That would imply that, by default, your implementation doesn't grow in size.  And what about `ArrayList(int, int)`, when a _negative_ increment (or capacity) is supplied?  Don't forget your bounds checking!  You may find it useful to define a default increment, although I think usually it's percentage based.  You may also want to push everything though one 'base' constructor, that the others reference to hide complexity.

Comment: Have a look at my answer I think it should solve your problems. And mind @X-Zero's comment.

Answer (score 2):

Since you **implement** an interface, you must **implement** all of the methods it declares (unless your class is `abstract`). Have a look at the [Java tutorial trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/usinginterface.html) on inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

You implement the interface `List` so you need to **implement** all method which are defined in this interface. The exception says you should add the method `iterator()` to `ArrayList`.

An interface is like a contract which you (your class) sign(s). You have to fulfill everything which is defined in the contract or in other words you need to implement every (abstract) method from the interface.

**Edit:** I cleaned up the code and now the *only* thing you have to do is to implement every method with a `// TODO` comment in it.

```
public class ArrayList<E> implements List<E> {
    private Object[] elementData;

    private int elementCount;
    private int capacityIncrement;

    private static final int INVALID_INDEX = -1;
    private static final int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 100;

    public ArrayList() {
        capacityIncrement = 0;
        elementData = new Object[DEFAULT_CAPACITY];
    }

    public ArrayList(int capacity) {
        this.capacityIncrement = 0;
        this.elementData = new Object[capacity];
    }

    public ArrayList(int capacity, int increment) {
        this.capacityIncrement = increment;
        this.elementData = new Object[capacity];
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(E element) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void add(E element) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public boolean remove(E element) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public E elementAt(int index) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int indexOf(E element) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void insertElementAt(E element, int index) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void removeElementAt(int index) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void setElementAt(E element, int index) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void removeDuplicates() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void trimToSize() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<E> iterator() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<E> iterator(int index) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    protected class ArrayListIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {
        private ArrayList<T> list;

        private ArrayListIterator(ArrayList<T> list) {
            this.list = list;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public T next() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void remove() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }
}

interface List<T> {
    public int size();

    public boolean isEmpty();

    public void clear();

    public boolean contains(T element);

    public void add(T element);

    public boolean remove(T element);

    public T elementAt(int index);

    public int indexOf(T element);

    public void insertElementAt(T element, int index);

    public void removeElementAt(int index);

    public void setElementAt(T element, int index);

    public void removeDuplicates();

    public void trimToSize();

    public Iterator<T> iterator();

    public Iterator<T> iterator(int index);

    public String toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An interface is a contract that states that certain functionality will be provided by any class that implements it. That's done by specifying each of the method signatures (but, generally, no method bodies - so there's no actual implementation logic). So, if you have a class that implements that interface, you have to provide implementations for each of the methods so that your class fulfills that contract.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are saying that your class "implements List", it must implement all methods defined in the List interface. An interface is like an abstract specification for your class, specifying what your class can do (its methods) without giving an details about what your class contains/how it does its work

Comment: WHen I used the auto correct in NetBeans it says statements after each method "throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");" why?

Comment: If you auto-implement these methods in your IDE, it will typically add these kind of exceptions to remind you that you have to implement them. The exception is just temporary stub code.